# Outlook Interop Exception HRESULT: 0xCA140115

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I have some pretty basic code that seems to work for most people but there's at least one workstation that throws this HRESULT code when it runs these couple lines of code:

```
Outlook.Application _OutlookInstance = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Stores stores = _OutlookInstance.Session.Stores;
```

Any idea what HRESULT code 0xCA140115 is or what it means? I can't find it on MSDN anywhere...

The workstation that experiences the problem is at a remote call center location, so I can't do any immediate testing/debugging, or easily see what is specifically different about this workstation versus the others. I would imagine there might be more workstations at that same call center that could have the error, but this code is still in the testing phase.

Comment: What property or method exactly fires an exception? Where and when do you run the code listed above?

Comment: This is a testing application - a winforms app that starts and immediately runs those two lines (the rest of the code isn't hit since it throws the exception). It's hard to say at the moment which specific property or method triggers it since I can't test very easily (only the remote user can reproduce it so far, so I'm bound to his availability to test)

Comment: What Outlook version is installed on the machine? Is it the Click2Run edition?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, but I was able to get through several more iterations of testing and find out what the issue was. First off, my original post was incorrect. The code flow made it seem like the error was happening during those 2 initial lines, but it was actually happening a little later, when I was looping through the stores, like this:

```
Outlook.Stores stores = _OutlookInstance.Session.Stores;
foreach(Outlook.Store store in stores) // <----- THIS LINE
{
  ...
}
```

Each time the user ran this, he would get a different HRESULT error code:

0xCA140115

0xAF64011D

0xC1F4011D

0xC834011D

The only consistent factor was the "4011" in the middle.

When I upped the logging, I could see that the user had 18 mailboxes and the foreach() loop was getting through the first 3 but failing on the 4th. The 4th mailbox was a "Public Folders" store associated to another mailbox that was added in a different way than the rest of the mailboxes (it had something to do with it being an Outlook 365 mailbox that required different authentication).

So essentially it ended up being that any attempt to even touch that particular mailbox/store (including the "store" variable being set) would result in that COM exception.

I was able to work around it by looping through stores via numeric index so that the setting of "store" was inside my try/catch block, like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < stores.Count; i++)
{
  try
  {
    Outlook.Store store = stores[i];
    ...
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now when the loop hit that particular store, I could tell that it was Outlook saying that the server wasn't available, and the store was an online-only store, so the store couldn't be accessed.

I'm still not certain about why the error codes changed each time, but there you have it.